# How can I extract and download an app which uses android app bundle(aab) for their libs?

Tags: android, android-studio, reverse-engineering, smali, apktool

I wanted to extract an app using the apk extractor app and download it on my other devices for testing and modifying it. I used to be able to do this with other apps but this one uses android app bundle for their libs meaning this app will only work if downloaded from Google play store since that's where the app bundle comes from. Is there any way I could extract the libs from the bundle or extract the whole .abb file somehow to make this apk work even when not downloaded from Google playstore?

Answer (score 0):

Apktool accepts `.apk` files as input, therefore you first need to generate `.apk` files from a given `.abb` App Bundle package.

This can be achieved using [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool):

> `bundletool` is the underlying tool that Gradle, Android Studio, and
>   Google Play use to build an Android App Bundle or convert an app
>   bundle into the various APKs that are deployed to devices.
>   `bundletool` is also available to you as a command line tool, so you
>   can recreate, inspect, and verify Google Play’s server-side build of
>   your app’s APKs.

---

After downloading the latest [release](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases), you can run the following command (the jar file name might change):

```
$ java -jar bundletool-all-0.10.2.jar build-apks --mode=universal --bundle=./app.aab --output=./my_app.apks
```

The arguments are:

> **--bundle=path** (Required) Specifies the path to the app bundle you built using Android Studio.
>   **--output=path** (Required) Specifies the name of the output `.apks` file, which contains all the APK artifacts for your app.
>   **--mode=universal**  Set the mode to universal if you want bundletool to build only a single APK that includes all of your app's code and resources such that the APK is compatible with all device configurations your app supports.

The output file (`my_app.apks`) is just a zip file containing `.apk` files.
Since we've specified the `--mode=universal` setting, this archive will only contain a singe `.apk` file called `universal.apk`. You can use it as an input to `apktool`.